# Unexpected Unrecoverable Error SQL Import Wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-import-wizard

I'm using Microsoft SQL server management studio 2018, I created a new database and import some excel files, tables were created automatically through SQL server Import Wizard all of sudden when I tried to import another excel file through same import procedure but an error came up in a dialog box with three buttons.

> Unexpected Unrecoverable Error
>
> Abort Retry Ignore

I tried some solution but none of them works for me.

Please help me through this.

Error Screenshot Attached Below.

[image]

Comment: Please can you share with us what have you tried ? "I tried some solution but none of them works for me." Cheers!

Comment: I tried this:
 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e8be2b2a-57f9-485e-90df-2f857f3a0c55/ssis-importexport-wizard-quotunexpected-unrecoverable-errorquot?forum=sqltools
@VBoka

Comment: And this: http://www.varindersandhu.in/2012/08/20/ssis-importexport-wizard-unexpected-unrecoverable-error/

Comment: Okay let me try this one thanks @VBoka

Comment: You are welcome. Hope it will help...

Comment: the solution you gave is also not working in my case @VBoka

Comment: Have you tried the both options? There are 1 or 2 option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the tool in 64 bit mode from the Start Menu.